# Why is this Wrong? Pax Romana

Tags: knowledge

What's wrong with this?

> ABCDEFGILMNOPQRSTVXYZ
>
> Pax Romana my friends. May the peace of Rome be upon us! Bless Caesar, Pax Romana.

Please explain *thouroughly* rather than just saying the answer or taking a random guess.

There is only one answer to this.

Comment: **J**, **U** and **W** are missing???

Comment: Ahh but that would be too easy wouldn't my friend?

Comment: I wouldn't make it *that* easy for you would I?

Comment: The K and the H is also missing, I had to make a quick edit

Comment: Since the OP has already accepted an answer, I guess the correct response is not "the tag `kowledge` is misspelled".

Comment: Thank you boboquack for changing that and @shoover for pointing that out. I had not noticed. "Kowledge" lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alphabet should be ACDEFGIJLMNOPQRSTVXYZ instead.

> Applying the [Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) to the missing letters in the original (HJKUW) we get IKLVX. If instead we add the J back and remove the B, the result is CILVX, the five smallest roman numerals.

Obviously, one also usually spells "of" with an "o" :-)

Comment: Nice job, you got it. I *seriously* need to create a puzzle that doesn't take five munites for somebody to solve  Especially afte spending several hours trying to make one. Back to the drawing board....

Comment: @North, for what it's worth, it was a very nice 5-minute puzzle. :-)

Comment: @North I think this is your nicest one yet. I like the Roman/Caesar theme!

Answer (score 4):

Cracked screen on phone like mine just about while trying to type the alphabet is the simplest answer.

Comment: Which would be a good (and hilarious) answer if the question were tagged with `lateral-thinking` instead of `knowledge` and `trivia` :-)

Comment: Creative and lol. +1

Comment: Now I'm confused what's the difference between critical and hilarious thinking and knowledge and trivia. I find humor in both.